# Database performance with large rows

Tags: mysql, performance, large-data

I have a requirement where I need to get information about a particular column in a very large table. The values in the column are not unique and are repeated more than once. So to get unique information it becomes an expensive operation to traverse the entire table.

Is there a design strategy that will save time and improve the database performance?

Comment: By "Large rows" do you mean the column is large or the rows are large or the number of rows is large?  In either case the obvious answer is to use an index but maybe there's some more information you can give us.

Comment: The number of rows is large, also the value in not unique

Comment: Do you need the entire column?  Do you need the entire row?  What "information" do you need about a column?  Perhaps `LENGTH(col)`?  Something else?  Please clarify the question(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you would have a new table with your unique values and a key.  You refer to that table via the key from your original table.  You then have a table that answers your question.